# CMake: How to compile based on different main entries

Tags: c++, cmake

Suppose that I've got two `main` entries, one in `main1.cpp` and one in `main2.cpp` (there are other files too, but only two main entries). How can I configure the `CMakeLists.txt` file so that I can include either `main1.cpp` or `main2.cpp` based on different targets? i.e. I will eventually be able to use "make target1" to produce `exec1` based on `main1.cpp` and "make target2" to produce `exec2` based on `main2.cpp` along with other files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like a case for making a library out of all your sources except the mains.  Then just add two executable targets, each linked to the library.

```
add_executable(MyExe1 main1.cpp)
add_executable(MyExe2 main2.cpp)
add_library(MyLib <all the other files>)

target_link_libraries(MyExe1 MyLib)
target_link_libraries(MyExe2 MyLib)
```

You *can* just include all the sources twice, so `MyExe1` would have everything except main2.cpp, and `MyExe2` everything except main1.cpp, but this would involve compiling the sources twice and is inefficient.